# Time complexity of recursive function find(n)

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

```
void find (int n) {
    if (n < 2) return;
    else {
        sum = 0;

        for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) find(n / 2); 
        for (i = 1; i <= n*n; i++)
            sum = sum +1;
    }
}
```

Assume that the division operation takes constant time and `sum` is a global variable. What is the **time complexity** of `find(n)`?

According to me: Since first for loop run `4 log n` times and second for loop run `n^2` times.
So the total time complexity = `O(4 log n + n^2) = O(n^2)`.

Comment: I reformatted your code for readability. And, please specify your target programming language with a tag if you can.

Comment: People usually find out if they got the right answer on their homework by handing it in and waiting for the teacher to comment on it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because because because because!

Comment: Take a look at [recurrence relations](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rweba/algf09/solverecurrencesSF.pdf). Then you could use the master theorem to potentially prove.

Comment: Didn't know ≤ was a C operator.

Comment: Also, looks like someone just got permission to make close votes (not me, I like your question)!

Comment: The answer is wrong btw

Comment: If it was right, he wouldn't be asking...

Comment: So we close? or I answer this? ( so far: +1) ...

Comment: @umang good you corrected the <=, but you should also remove the *then*.

Answer (score 4):

```
T(n) = 4 * T(n/2) + O(n^2)
a = 4, b = 2, f(n) = n^2
f(n) = O(n^c log^k(n)) , c = 2, k = 0
logb(a) = log2(4) = 2, c = logb(a)
T(n) = Theta(n^(logb(a))log^(k+1)n) = Theta(n^2*log^1(n)) = Theta(n^2*log(n))
```

Case 2 of the master theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 1):

The first loop excutes O(log(n)) times, each time calling itself.
Upon returning, each invocation will invoke a O(n^2) loop.

Therefore, `O(n^2 log(n))`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. `n^2 + (n/2)^2 + (n/4)^2 + ..` is in O(n^2) because it is less than 2*(n^2). You can fill all smaller squares in larger one.

This would hold even if there would be O(n) as last loop.

For example

```
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) find(n / 2); 
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    sum = sum +1;
```

has complexity of O(n)